# Start pacemaker on boot in debian

Tags: debian, boot, pacemaker

I'm using corosync and pacemaker on a debian, and at each reboot I need to start pacemaker by hand. Is there a solution to make it happend automaticaly?

Tanks a lot.

Comment: Does the page at http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try enabeling them with update-rc.d It's the same way you do it in ubuntu [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2263/chkconfig-alternative-for-ubuntu-server)?

```
update-rc.d pacemaker defaults
update-rc.d corosync defaults
```